# Thymeleaf if + each order

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I'm doing the following:

```
<p th:if="${foo != null}" th:each="row : ${foo.values().iterator().next().rowKeySet()}">
```

`foo` is an instance of `java.util.Map`.

```
Thymeleaf throws an `TemplateProcessingException: 
Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "foo.values().iterator().next().value.rowKeySet()"` with root cause `SpelEvaluationException: EL1011E:(pos 22): 
Method call: Attempted to call method values() on null context object`.
```

Why Thymeleaf processes `th:each` when the result of `th:if` is `false` and how to solve it?

This is my current dirty workaround:

```
<p th:if="${foo != null}" th:each="row : ${foo != null ? foo.values().iterator().next().rowKeySet() : null}">
```

Comment: First check if `foo.values().iterator().hasnext()` is true and then call `foo.values().iterator().next()`

Comment: `foo` is already null

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thymeleaf processes `th:each` before `th:if` because defines Attribute Precedence which establishes the order in which tags are evaluated, this is explained [here](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#attribute-precedence).

As a work you could wrap the `th:each` expression, for example:

```
<div th:if="${foo != null}">
    <p th:each="row : ${foo.values().iterator().next().rowKeySet()}">
    ...
```

I don't know the context in which you are working, but as a reference, you could easily iterate over a map using Thymeleaf ([docs](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#iterable-values)).

Comment: I only need the first entry of the map in this case, but maybe moving this to the java object itself would be a better solution. I can't wrap the tag as it is an `<li>` element. I just wrote it as `<p>` for the snippet.